# Primary Key for table which purges after particular intervals

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am going to create new table having row_id as primary key whoes value gets auto increment by 1. This table is generally audit table & may get purged after particular intervals. Is there any other possibility of primary key ?. Other columns in table are not unique in nature.

The reason I worried is suppose if table is purged till 32000 as row ID, new records will have row id as 32001, wasting numbering till 32000.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Our databases have been running for more than twenty years and have tables with millions of records (and thus many more audit update records in the audit tables) for all that time and we are not even close to running out of ids and if we were were could switch to bigint and probably run for well over 100 years before running out. So exactly why is it a problem that you have deleted some records?

Comment: I thought it will be bad design to use auto increment column as primary key when we know that we are ultimately going to delete/purge the records.I am working on finance project where we may have to audit huge number of records on daily basis that's why above question came into my mind. **One of my friend suggested me to use current dateTimeStamp as primary key** however there might be possiblity to get SQLIntegrityException when two audit entries trying to insert at same time(although we have microseconds). BIGINT will give me good sleep for some years however to be honest it is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about that, you can use this to reset the auto incrementing number. I'm assuming you're using SQL Server.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)
```

Another approach would be to just use a `uniqueidentifier` instead of an `integer`.

Comment: I am using DB2.
I am not going to purge whole table when purge request comes; it will happen to delete last month's records. So is it ok to reset auto incrementing number ? What if collosion occurs ?

**I appreciate your way of thinking**, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your responses; I am going with BIGINT datatype provided by IBM DB2, because the size it has provided is **9223372036854775808** which is enough to audit records atleast 100 years :)